# Matching Variables using Powershell Match

Tags: powershell, match

I need to parse some config files and find a match. I've simplified the problem to this. Why doesn't powershell match the backslash even when it's been escaped? It works if I remove the backspace from the code below.

Find $b in $a:

```
$a="lorum [\test] ipsum"
$b="[\test]" 

([regex]::Escape($a )) -match ([regex]::Escape($b))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you're escaping the string itself. The part before `-match` should be a normal string, while the part after needs to be a regex pattern. What your command actually does is comparing these strings(think of them as normal strings):

```
"lorum \[\\test\] ipsum" contains "[\test]"
```

Which is never true. Try matching the string `$a` to the escaped pattern `$b`:

```
$a="lorum [\test] ipsum"
$b="[\test]" 

$a -match ([regex]::Escape($b))
```